# Having problems identifying onTabReselected status when using fragments. Selected and Unselected work OK but is not identified when Reselected

Tags: android, android-fragments

When trying to Reselect a fragment it never happens as it is selected instead of reselected. I need to continue typing the textfields where was initially selected the fragments.

Also I am getting the following logcat information when executed....
2024-01-14 11:28:30.704 28045-28045 UNSELECTED POSITION 1 com.hugo.fragments I TRUE 2024-01-14 11:28:30.706 28045-28045 SELECTED POSITION 0 com.hugo.fragments I TRUE 2024-01-14 11:28:30.754 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Failure getting entry for 0x7f050259 (t=4 e=601) (error -75) 2024-01-14 11:28:30.755 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Failure getting entry for 0x7f050259 (t=4 e=601) (error -75) 2024-01-14 11:28:30.802 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f050259 which is invalid or in a cycle. 2024-01-14 11:28:30.802 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f050259 which is invalid or in a cycle. 2024-01-14 11:28:30.815 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Failure getting entry for 0x7f050259 (t=4 e=601) (error -75) 2024-01-14 11:28:30.815 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Failure getting entry for 0x7f050259 (t=4 e=601) (error -75) 2024-01-14 11:28:30.852 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f050259 which is invalid or in a cycle. 2024-01-14 11:28:30.853 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f050259 which is invalid or in a cycle. 2024-01-14 11:28:30.865 28045-28045 ResourceType com.hugo.fragments W Failure getting entry for 0x7f050259 (t=4 e=601) (error -75)

Tried modifying the getSupportFragmentManager() repalcing the TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN to TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_MATCH_ACTIVITY_OPEN but it remains the same.

```
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

// Initialize to display first fragement
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.framelayout, new FirstFragment())
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .commit();

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

    // onTabSelected works OK
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                Log.i("SELECTED POSITION 0", "TRUE");
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.i("SELECTED POSITION 1", "TRUE");
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();

    }

    // onTabUnselected works OK
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                Log.i("UNSELECTED POSITION 0", "TRUE");
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.i("UNSELECTED POSITION 1", "TRUE");
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
                break;
        }
    }

    // it is never referenced onTabReSelected
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                Log.i("RESELECTED POSITION 0", "TRUE");
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.i("RESELECTED POSITION 1", "TRUE");
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();

    }

});
```